# SSRS Show a different section of the report if another is empty

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am looking at creating an invoice type report. ON the details page there is a section for each item that could be listed. If an item has no values then I have set that table to be hidden using `CountRows() = 0` how can I then set another section to be displayed when this section is empty. Such as an offers section or a summary of what that service could be?

Comment: That was the incorrect syntax but the right idea, did countrows() <> 0 and it looks to be working thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad, could also have done CountRows() > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CountRows()<>0** or **CountRows()>0**